# CefSharp inside a Control

Tags: vb.net, winforms, cefsharp

When I attempt to add CefSharp to a Panel or Groupbox it doesn't display anything (by that I mean that the webbrowser doesn't show, even a blank page, only the control background is visible as if there is nothing added).

But when I use "Me" instead, it works normally. Why is that? Is it not possible to add it to wherever you want?

---

```
Public Class Form_Main  
    Private WithEvents chromeBrowser As ChromiumWebBrowser
    Public Sub InitializeChromium()
        InitializeComponent()
        Dim CEF_settings As New CefSettings With {
            .CachePath = "Cache"
        }
        CefSharp.Cef.Initialize(CEF_settings)
        chromeBrowser = New ChromiumWebBrowser("www.google.com") With {
            .Dock = DockStyle.Fill
        }
        Panel1.Controls.Add(chromeBrowser) 'With Me.Controls.Add(chromeBrowser) it works
    End Sub

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        InitializeChromium()
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: The Minimal example uses a toolstrip container and that works just fine see https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp.MinimalExample/blob/master/CefSharp.MinimalExample.WinForms/BrowserForm.cs#L27 try modifying the example to reproduce your problem

Comment: @amaitland Using the minimal example from the cef website https://thechriskent.com/2014/08/18/embedded-chromium-in-winforms/ works, but the webbrowser stops showing as soon as I change the control container to anything other that Form (Me). Those 6 letters are the only difference https://i.imgur.com/j49nRei.png

Comment: Try modifying the official example I linked above.  That article is almost 5years old.

Comment: @amaitland Does it matter how old is it if it works, but stops working when I change the browsers parent from form to panel?

Comment: The article as a whole is outdated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know why, but changing the Method name to "New" fixes it.

So instead of

```
Public Sub InitializeChromium()
'Stuff"
End Sub
```

it must be

```
Public Sub New()
'Stuff"
End Sub
```

---

Now the webbrowser gets displayed no matter where it's placed.

Answer (score -2):

At your Program, You must not to use `InitializeComponent()`.
Remove it from all of the codes.